# How does the YiiBase class include the files

Tags: php, yii

How does the YiiBase class include the files required in the function "createApplication"??

```
 public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
    {
            return new $class($config);
    }
```

I couldn't find the way YiiBase includes "CWebApplication.php" when creating an Yii application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `YiiBase` class, at the end of the file you can see:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

This will "bind" the `__autoload` magic method to the `autoload` method of `YiiBase`.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.autoload.php

In this `YiiBase` `autoload` method we can see that it uses $_coreClasses variable to try to include the class that is asked.

```
...
if(isset(self::$classMap[$className]))
    include(self::$classMap[$className]);
elseif(isset(self::$_coreClasses[$className]))
    include(YII_PATH.self::$_coreClasses[$className]);
...
```

And this variable contains all the core yii classes:

```
private static $_coreClasses=array(
    'CApplication' => '/base/CApplication.php',
    'CApplicationComponent' => '/base/CApplicationComponent.php',
    'CBehavior' => '/base/CBehavior.php',
    'CComponent' => '/base/CComponent.php',
    'CErrorEvent' => '/base/CErrorEvent.php',
    'CErrorHandler' => '/base/CErrorHandler.php',
    ...
);
```